# Remove elements from array based on filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I remove elements from array based on a filter, remove only those indexes when 'quantity' is 0 and 'isSelected' is false? Any suggestion. Here is my code:

```
<table data-ng-repeat="st in Absorb track by $index" data-ng-cloak data-ng-init="remove(st)">                                          
    <tr>
        <td>                                                    
            <input type="radio" name="groupName" data-ng-model ="st.isSelected" data-ng-checked="(st.isSelected == true)"/>
        </td>
        <td>                                                       
            <span>{{st.ProjectedQuantityOnHand}}</span>
        </td>
        <td style="display:none" data-ng-if="st.ProjectedQuantityOnHand == 0">                                                       
            <input type="number" data-ng-model="st.ProjectedQuantityOnHand" style="display:none">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.Absorb = [
    {"Name":"apple", ProjectedQuantityOnHand:"0", isSelected:true},
    {"Name":"mango", ProjectedQuantityOnHand:"0", isSelected:false}
    {"Name":"ball", ProjectedQuantityOnHand:"1", isSelected:false}
    {"Name":"football", ProjectedQuantityOnHand:"1", isSelected:false}
]

$scope.remove = function (item) {
     var availableqauantity = 0
     debugger
     angular.forEach($scope.StockList, function (i) {
        var FilteredProduct1 = $filter('filter')($scope.StockList, { isSelected: false, ProjectedQuantityOnHand: 0 });
        if (FilteredProduct1.length > 0) {
            availableqauantity = FilteredProduct1[0].ProjectedQuantityOnHand;
        if (availableqauantity == 0)
            $scope.StockList.splice(i,1);
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want to remove these items from the array or do you want them just not to display?

Comment: @Eddi ya just don't want to display them

Comment: for angulars 1.x or 2? in angular 2 you would do filtering within your component's class rather than in the template with the filter pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table data-ng-repeat="st in Absorb | filter:{isSelected: '!false', ProjectedQuantityOnHand: '!0'} track by $index" data-ng-cloak>
```

This will show only those items, which have isSelected different than false and ProjectedQuantityOnHand different than 0. No need for external function.

**UPDATE**

https://plnkr.co/edit/gPz5pKSIOxZ6odSU3TfF?p=preview

Check this example. Here I've made a custom filter to hide items only when ProjectedQuantityOnHand is 0 and isSelected is false.

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(values) {
    var filtderResult = [];
    angular.forEach(values, function(value) {
      if (value.isSelected || value.ProjectedQuantityOnHand !== 0) {
        filtderResult.push(value);
      }
    });
    return filtderResult;
  }
});
```

Comment: i guess this will not work in my case. i have to hide only those elements where projectedquantity is 0 and have to show all whether it is selected or not doesnt matter. take an example, 
suppose projectedquantity is 0 but if it is selected then i have to show that element .
it will work filter:{isSelected: '!false'} but it will only show the selected record right ?

Comment: You can can remove isSelected: '!false' to hide only {ProjectedQuantityOnHand: 0} elements. Or there is some other function for isSelected property?

Comment: yeah having other functions also. i post only those codes which is based on concept @hardy

Comment: So you need to display item when it is selected despite of ProjectedQuantityOnHand value? Is that correct?

Comment: take a look at my object , i have to hide only mango from this array, and have to show all those elements.

Comment: Please check update section in answer, it hides only mango. I've made custom filter to do this. You can define any conditions you wish in it.